# Delay on default action a tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

Is it possible to make an delay on a default action?

I have this link and after i click it i show a hidden div with content. Then i want to slide down to that div with my screen, so the new div is top of my screen, but my problem is that after i click the button it takes some time for the div to animate out and therefor i need some kind of delay so the scrollto will fire after the div has become visible.

i made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/Ptd4n/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-div">
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a id="activate-two" href="#second">Link2</a>
        <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second-div" id="second">
        <a id="activate-three" href="#third">Link1</a>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
        <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="third-div" id="third">
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
        <a id="activate-four" href="#">Link3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {background-color:#F60;}
.first-div {background-color:#CCC;}
.first-div, .second-div, .third-div {height:1200px;}
.second-div, .third-div {display:none;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#activate-two").click(function(){
            $("#second").animate({
            height:'show'
            });
        });
        });
```

Comment: Does .delay() not work? http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help you :

```
$("#activate-two").click(function(){
   $("#second").show("100",function(){
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top }, 'slow');
   })
});
```

Here is a updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ptd4n/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a delay, you need to utilize the `.animate` callback function:

```
$("#activate-two").click(function(){
    $("#second").animate({
        height:'show'
    }, function() {
        //Fire your scroll function here!
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a delay, as such - use a callback.

jQuery animations have a [complete function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete) that will fire when your animation is finished. Then you can scroll to your object in its final location.